# Añadir datos en Firebase database andorid

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, firebase

Estoy desarrollando una app en la que tengo un registro de usuarios por medio de la autenticacion de Firebase, por correo y contraseña.

Quiero que los usuarios puedan modificar sus datos y los datos modificados que aparezcan en FirebaseDatabase teniendo un identificador por cada usuario que sea su email.

Quiero hacerlo asi para que los usuarios puedan editar su usuario y añadir los mas datos de los que pide la autentificacion.

Por ahora solo he consegido almacenar datos con un id aleatorio.

```
   btnModificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            usuario.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            editTextEmail.setText(user.getEmail());

            usuario.setNombreUsuario(editTextNombreUsuario.getText().toString());
            usuario.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
            usuario.setNombreEmpresa(editTextNombreEmpresa.getText().toString());
            usuario.setTelefono(editTextTelefono.getText().toString());
            usuario.setCalle(editTextCalle.getText().toString());
            usuario.setCiudad(editTextCiudad.getText().toString());
            usuario.setCodigoPostal(editTextCodigoPostal.getText().toString());
            usuario.setProvincia(editTextprovincia.getText().toString());

            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Usuario").push();
            myRef.child("Email").setValue(usuario.getEmail());
            myRef.child("NombreUsuario").setValue(usuario.getNombreUsuario());
            myRef.child("NombreEmpresa").setValue(usuario.getNombreEmpresa());
            myRef.child("Telefono").setValue(usuario.getTelefono());
            myRef.child("Calle").setValue(usuario.getCalle());
            myRef.child("Ciudad").setValue(usuario.getCiudad());
            myRef.child("CodigoPostal").setValue(usuario.getCodigoPostal());
            myRef.child("Provincia").setValue(usuario.getProvincia());

            Intent intent = new Intent(ModificarDatosActivity.this,InicioActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Lo cual me devuelve en firebase:

```
{
"Usuario" : {
    "-LcIUriNhg8Mv_1IDjQW" : {
        "Calle" : "",
        "Ciudad" : "",
        "CodigoPostal" : "",
        "Email" : "acoidanns@gmail.com",
        "NombreEmpresa" : "Acoidan Francisco",
        "NombreUsuario" : "Acoidan Francisco",
        "Provincia" : "",
        "Telefono" : "+34666160876"
    },
    "-LcIUzGCRe7eoqcefPxk" : {
        "Calle" : "",
        "Ciudad" : "",
        "CodigoPostal" : "",
        "Email" : "acoidanns@gmail.com",
        "NombreEmpresa" : "Acoidanns",
        "NombreUsuario" : "Acoidan Francisco",
        "Provincia" : "",
        "Telefono" : "+34666160876"
    },
    "-LcIXnifqkj0VHcXNS8I" : {
        "Calle" : "",
        "Ciudad" : "",
        "CodigoPostal" : "",
        "Email" : "acoidanns@gmail.com",
        "NombreEmpresa" : "acoidan",
        "NombreUsuario" : "acoidan",
        "Provincia" : "",
        "Telefono" : "+34666160876"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, tu no podrías usar el email como identificador si te refieres a que sea a algo como esto:

```
{ "Usuario" : {
    "acoidanns@gmail.com" : {
        "Calle" : "",
        "Ciudad" : "",
        "CodigoPostal" : "",
        "Email" : "acoidanns@gmail.com",
        "NombreEmpresa" : "Acoidan Francisco",
        "NombreUsuario" : "Acoidan Francisco",
        "Provincia" : "",
        "Telefono" : "+34666160876"
    }
```

Ya que firebase no permite algunos caracteres como '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Lo que yo te recomiendo hacer o usar sería el UID que te proporciona firebase, sería algo como esto con tu mismo código

```
  btnModificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        usuario.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        editTextEmail.setText(user.getEmail());

        usuario.setNombreUsuario(editTextNombreUsuario.getText().toString());
        usuario.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
        usuario.setNombreEmpresa(editTextNombreEmpresa.getText().toString());
        usuario.setTelefono(editTextTelefono.getText().toString());
        usuario.setCalle(editTextCalle.getText().toString());
        usuario.setCiudad(editTextCiudad.getText().toString());
        usuario.setCodigoPostal(editTextCodigoPostal.getText().toString());
        usuario.setProvincia(editTextprovincia.getText().toString());

        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Usuario").child(user.getUid());
        myRef.child("Email").setValue(usuario.getEmail());
        myRef.child("NombreUsuario").setValue(usuario.getNombreUsuario());
        myRef.child("NombreEmpresa").setValue(usuario.getNombreEmpresa());
        myRef.child("Telefono").setValue(usuario.getTelefono());
        myRef.child("Calle").setValue(usuario.getCalle());
        myRef.child("Ciudad").setValue(usuario.getCiudad());
        myRef.child("CodigoPostal").setValue(usuario.getCodigoPostal());
        myRef.child("Provincia").setValue(usuario.getProvincia());

        Intent intent = new Intent(ModificarDatosActivity.this,InicioActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Lo que hago es que en vez de esta linea de código que tú tienes

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Usuario").push();
```

La reemplazo por esta

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Usuario").child(user.getUid());
```

Ya que si haces un ".push" se crea un documento o nodo diferente, y al utilizar el UID del usuario que es único, mantienes por separado la información de los usuarios y no se duplica.

No tengo tu código de como registras el usuario así que en esa parte no te puedo ayudar por ahora.

Comment: El UID de los usuarios es unico lo hice tal y como aparece en los tutoriales de Firebase, muchas gracias no habia caido en el uso del UID que genera firebase. Muchas gracias